# Is there a limit in mysql for changing databases?

Tags: mysql, ruby

our database server has few thousands of databases and while doing a specific search, I need to check them all.

Currently, I make connection to each of those, do the search and disconnect - this works, but of course has some overhead (reconnecting few thousands times) which I want to get rid of.

I tried something like:

```
companies.each do |company|
    rs = con.query("SELECT * FROM #{company[:schema_id]}.properties")

    rs.num_rows.times do
        puts rs.fetch_row.join("\s")
    end

end
```

But it crashes in 30th company with:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `e' for <name of app>
```

the company[:schema_id] is a hash and I checked it - it does not event start with 'e' letter. I also tried to do 'USE newdatabase' and do just simple query, but again, It died when I changed DB for 30th time.

I also tried to reset the connection every 25 queries, but the second connection crashed on 5th query (which again sums up with 30), so this wont help.

Is this some limitation of mysql? I could not google anything or find anything in mysql configuration.

UPDATE: the code is ruby and the error I get while crashing is:

```
Mysql2::Error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'databasename.properties WHERE tenant = 0 AND name = ' at line 1:
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Few thousand databases` on 1 server?

Comment: Why don't you use a single connection and queries like `FROM <databasename>.<tablename> ...`? I'm impressed by the number of databases just like Hanky 웃 Panky.

Comment: I cannot help it, I was not the one creating this database system. and I tried <dbname>.<table>, but again, it crashes on the 30th query

Comment: I don't know what kind of code we're looking at here (e.g python?) but the error seems to be generated from that. I believe this is not a mysql error.

So you should probably tag your question with the codinglanguage you are using and seek it there. It seems that there is something wrong with that variable you are using. Try to print it to the screen as debug info before executing the query. It might give you the solution.

Comment: I have had a similar issue when using the odbc drivers to connect to MS Access databases (~1000 of them). Trying to remember how I fixed it. From memory I landed up closing the connection and unsetting the connecting variable (but possibly doing some other things as well)

Comment: The code is ruby, Iam goint to update the questions. Also I have the error message (the 'e' was mistake on my part)

Comment: How are you creating the connections to the Mysql database?  A reliable crash on the 30th attempt smells like a resource starvation issue to me.  Are you closing your connections and freeing system resources in between queries?

Comment: If you have a few thousand databases, then you MUST be some kind of professional database host. Surely, *we* should be asking *you* !?!

Comment: We offer a service and unfortunately, it was designed, that each registered company has its own database, thats why this number. Iam developing a tool, just for could operations team for searching through those companies (like what company has enabled this and that) which is why I need to go through all databases. Developers told me that their app servers (java based) do this exactly like that, so it should be server issues, but this script in ruby keeps dying. I make one connection and I want to do everything in one connection (answer to previous questions)

Comment: @user3337015 What's the name of this database exactly? Presumably you can't tell us, but check if you have to [quote this name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: name of the db is hash, but it was it... I did not put it inside `` and it just happened, that the 30th hash was not liked by mysql server. Thanks for all yout help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that database was not in `` and it just happened that the 30th hash (database name) was not liked by mysql server.